# Is there a difference between using Live Data as a parameter and using return?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I create functions in ViewModel to avoid repetition when using Flow and LiveData. In an example, I created an extension function as follows. While talking to my friend, we started to think about the difference between using it as a parameter and using it by returning, but I couldn't find much about it. Which method is correct?

```
inline fun <reified T> FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchToLiveData(
    key: String,
    gson: Gson,
    liveData: MutableLiveData<T>
) {
    this.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            val keyString = this.getString(key)
            val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
            val jsonModel = gson.fromJson<T>(keyString, type)
            liveData.postValue(jsonModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```
inline fun <reified T> FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchToLiveData(
     key: String,
     gson: gson
): LiveData<T> {
     val liveData = MutableLiveData<T>()
     this.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener {
         if (it.isSuccessful) {
             val keyString = this.getString(key)
             val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
             val jsonModel = gson.fromJson<T>(keyString, type)
             liveData.postValue(jsonModel)
         }
     }
     return liveData
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way makes sense if you are calling the function multiple times to change the published value of a LiveData while it is being observed. But if you’re not it’s convoluted.

The second way looks fine…

Except you could improve memory use by using the `liveData { }` coroutine builder and an `await()` call instead of a listener. This will make the API call cancellable and automatically cancelled when the ViewModel goes out of scope. For the first way this isn’t feasible and you would maybe want to launch a coroutine and use await inside it to update the live data.

Comment: I'm a new developer so how can I check for optimizing memory usage, canceling when out of scope as it may be needed in different instances? I've used tools like LeakCanary, are there any other tools and libraries I should know about?

Comment: I don’t know of any others to recommend.